# How to open default sources files using Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I just installed Visual Studio 2019 and the first time I build I see 416 Errors about default source files not loading: [image: 416 Errors about default source files not loading]

Comment: Can you please provide more information about your intents?

Answer (score 0):

You might have done one of the following mistakes :

**1. Bad include syntax**

You wrote

```c++
#include "stdio.h"
#include "ctype.h"
[...]
```

instead of

```c++
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
[...]
```

**2. Included C headers instead of C++ headers**

In C++, all C headers have been renamed: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/

Then you should use:

```c++
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctype>
[...]
```

**Note**

There rarely is need to use common C headers in C++ as C++ provide the same features with it own headers.

Comment: I have not touched anything about the install other than tell it I want C++ Desktop Development so I don't know how in the world it could have raised all those errors. I checked the code and it all looks fine.

Comment: Are you sure that your project is a C++ program?